# Are stored procedures faster/better then simple queries?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using stored procedures to retrieve data for a few requirements which I think cannot be achieved using simple queries.

But in general, are stored procedures better, faster and efficient than simple queries?

Comment: Yes, no, maybe, depends. Covered all the bases....

Comment: Care to stumble across this Question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208976/are-stored-procedures-faster-for-simple-queries?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a long debate but generally they are faster.

The reason why they are faster is

The Cache, it benefits in a way that the first time the stored procedure is executed, database server creates an execution plan, which is cached for reuse.

Pre-parsed SQL, no need to parse it every time.

Pre-generated query execution plan

Reduced network traffic

Ability to edit without recompiling

SQL injection attacks